# how to subtract a date from today in django model

Tags: python, django, date

**models.py**

```
import datetime as dt

 class Campaign(models.Model):
    enddate = models.DateField()


    def rest_of_the_day(self):
        now = dt.datetime.now().date()
        print('printing now value')
        print(now)
        print(self.campaign_enddate)
        return (self.campaign_enddate-now).days
```

**in views.py**

```
def landing_page(request):
    campaigns = Campaign.objects.all().order_by('-id')
    return render(request, 'core/landing_page.html',{'campaigns':campaigns})
```

**in html template**

```
      <span>{{campaign.rest_of_the_day}}</span>
```

I'm trying to store an end date and show the days left to the end date in html file using rest_of_the_day function in models.py

for example : if end date is 30-01-2010 and today is 15-01-2020, i want the rest_of_the_day to show 15

however, i get a **TypeError at / unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'datetime.date'**

Comment: That is because `self.campaigh_enddate is `None`, (likely it should be `self.enddate`?

Comment: What is `campaign_enddate` here?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem : when i do print(now) and print(self.campaign_enddate) i get the right dates in yyyy-mm-dd format. i just want now to subtract them and show the difference in number of days

Comment: @IrfanHarun: then likely the error is located somwhere else. What is the traceback you obtain in the response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that `self.campaign_enddate` is `None`. This makes sense, since it is not a field you defined. You can use the `enddate`:

```
class Campaign(models.Model):
    enddate = models.DateField()

    def rest_of_the_day(self):
        return (self.enddate-dt.date.today()).days
```

You can however make use of the [**`|timeuntil`** template filter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#timeuntil) here:

```
<span>{{ campaign.enddate|timeuntil }}</span>
```

THis makes it more convenient to process the amount of time until a certain date(time) happens.

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to use [database functions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/database-functions/) in a query to add column to QuerySet result.

Here each campaign object in QuerySet result will have `td` column of type `datetime.timedelta`.

```
from django.db.models.functions import Extract, Now, Trunc

campaigns = Campaign.objects.all().order_by('-id').annotate(
    td=F('enddate') - Now()
)
```

Or add [Trunc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/database-functions/#trunc) Result `td` column will be `datetime.timedelta` object with only days
We also need to cast calculations between date and datetime to one type / output_field.

```
campaigns = Campaign.objects.all().order_by('-id').annotate(
    td=Trunc(
        F('enddate') - Now(),
        'day',
        output_field=models.DateField()
    )
)
```

Note that you will be manipulating on `datetime.timedelta` object. Also, adding `Trunc` over different part (`Now()`, `F('enddate')`, `whole expression`, different combinations) may produce slightly different result due to how days will be rounded and substracted. You can experiment with that.

To get result as integer (*days*) [Extract](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/database-functions/#extract) function can be added to the mix:

```
campaigns = Campaign.objects.all().order_by('-id').annotate(
    td=Extract(
        F('enddate') - Trunc(Now(), 'day', output_field=models.DateField()),
        'day'
    )
)
```

Here `td` will be Integer.